# Hibernate/GORM - Handling multi-session domain object updating

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm curious about best practice when it comes to updating a domain object that may be updated by multiple sessions.

The call that occurs is AJAX from the g:remoteField tag. It takes the value and updates a domain object:

```
            person.refresh()
            person.isLeader = true
            person.save(flush:true)
```

I added a refresh prior to the update, since the value *could* be different.

Is this the best way to handle this? Is there a better way to handle updating? I don't particularly care if two people update at the same time in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I prefer to let the optimistic locking [do it's job](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking) and [override](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#optimisticLockingAndVersioning) it where I explicitly don't care if users stomp on each others' changes. <sub>(Note: these cases are few and far between)</sub>

What this means for highly ajaxy sites is that you have to have very solid error handling to cover update conflicts.